# mongoose and partial select/update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In node.js, when I use Mongoose:

is it possible to only fetch some of the values of a large object?

Is it possible to only update some of the values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fetch only certain fields, pass a string of field names as the second parameter in your `find`:

```javascript
// Include the first and last properties, and exclude _id
Model.find({}, 'first last -_id', callback)
```

or use the object notation as described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select):

```javascript
Model.find({}, {first: 1, last: 1, _id: 0}, callback)
```

To only update some of the properties, use an `update` with a [`$set`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$set) modifier:

```javascript
// Only update the name property
Model.update({_id: 12345}, {$set: {name: 'New name'}}, callback);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think with version 3.0.0 this was updated to

```
Model.find({}, 'first last', callback);
```

Where `first` and `last` are property names on the Model.