# Failed to update single property by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Frist I have read and try the solution in the post of [mongoose-and-partial-select-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655270/mongoose-and-partial-select-update).
However when I try to use the traditional style, query would work.

My schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            index: {
                unique: true,
                dropDups: true
            }
        },
        password: String,
        displayName: String,
        avatar: {
            type: String,
            default: "./img/user.png"
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        },
        ask_history: [
            {
                question_id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questionAnswer'
                },
                favorite: Boolean,
                ask_time: Date
            }
        ],
        interest: [String]
    }
})
```

Working Update function:

```
User.findById(id, function(err, User) {
            if (err) {
                throw done(err);
            }
            if (!User) {
                return;
            }
            User.local.role = "admin";
            User.save(function(err, updatedUser) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                } else {
                    //good
                }
            })
        });
```

However if I do this:

```
User.update({_id : id},
  {$set{
      local:{role:"admin"}
     }
  },function(...){...}
});
```

Code above will overwrite user into:

```
{
  _id : "...",
  local: {
          role : "admin"
         }
}
```

I read that $ will make the update only changing property, where I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The positional operator $ works with array of subdocuments.

In your case you have a single sub-document, so the following should work:

```
User.update({_id : id},
    { $set
        {
            "local.role": "admin"
        }
    }, function(...){...}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, can you tell me whats the difference when I use $set: {"local.role" : "admin"} vs $set: {local:{role : "admin"}}?

Comment: Here is what the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) says: **The $set operator expression has the following form: { $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }. *To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation).*** Hope that answers your question.